# export to excel issue in edge browser -Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, telerik-grid

```
 Protected Sub lnkExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lnkExport.Click
            Try
                Me.ThisPage = Session("PageName")
                Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(CurrentGridData.Tables(0))

                gvCaseView.AllowPaging = False
                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.DataSource = dv
                IsExport = True
                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.DataBind()

                ' Determine where grid was built in order to not export certain columns
                If CurrentViewID = "NEW" Then
                    ' Grid built in GetBoundColumnsForCustomer
                    If alUtil.CheckPermission("SUBMITCASES") Then
                        ' Additional columns are added for this permission
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(0).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(1).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(2).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(3).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(4).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(5).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(6).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(8).Visible = False
                    Else
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(0).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(1).Visible = False
                        Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(3).Visible = False
                    End If
                Else
                    ' Grid built in GetBoundColumns
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(0).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(1).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(2).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(3).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(4).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(5).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(6).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(7).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(8).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(9).Visible = False
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns(11).Visible = False
                End If
                If Not Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueNameSafe("completedIcon") Is Nothing Then
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.GetColumn("completedIcon").Visible = False
                End If
                If Not Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueNameSafe("company_name") Is Nothing Then
                    Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.GetColumn("company_name").Visible = True
                End If
                Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.GetColumn("case_id").Visible = True
                Me.gvCaseView.MasterTableView.GetColumn("support_level").Visible = False

                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.GridLines = GridLines.Both
                gvCaseView.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = True
                gvCaseView.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
                gvCaseView.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True
                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.AllowFilteringByColumn = True
                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.AllowSorting = False
                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.None
                gvCaseView.ExportSettings.FileName = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Session("Title").ToString)
                gvCaseView.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()

            Catch ex As Exception
                ReportError("lnkExport_Click", ex)
                Throw
            End Try

        End Sub
```

I have tried this piece of code and it is working fine with all the browsers except EDGE can anyone resolve it

Export to excel() function is totally undebuggable to trace out the issue

The downloading file is successful and the iisue is when opening the file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBn2n.png)

Comment: "the issue is when opening the file". What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @steven can u please check the link enter image description there u can find the image which exactly explains the problem which iam facing in opening a file in EDGE browser

Comment: That's just the file association thing asking you how you want to open files with .xls extension. Can't you just find Microsoft Excel, tick the Always use box, and OK?

Comment: Not an issue with the code because as you said the download is successful and the file should be available in your downloads folder, right? Maybe look around for Windows 10 or Edge forums such as this one: http://superuser.com/questions/993375/how-do-you-want-to-open-this-file

Comment: I just can't find excel option in the apps search so I have posted this question and thanks for the link and it didn't helped me in resolving the issue